# When using Tor, will a personal router log my traffic?

Tags: log, routers, address

If so, will it log the addresses of visited sites, just that I'm using Tor, or something else? I've gotten mixed answers from research, most saying that it'll only see I'm using Tor. However, it's unclear which router is being referred to in many answers--I'm talking *specifically* about the home router.

(New to Tor and internet anonymity in general)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
All other people can see that you use tor and encrypted data.

Comment: Alright, but how will this display in a router log? Will web addresses show?

Comment: If your router are logging all it can see is a relay's ip and encrypted data and that is worthless without the key.